# iOS audio over HDMI -- how to deal with 48khz sample rate?

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm been happily synthesizing audio (at 44.1khz) and sending it out through the RemoteIO audio unit. It's come to my attention that my app's audio is "garbled" when going out via HDMI to a certain model of TV. It looks to me like the problem is related to the fact that this TV is looking for audio data at 48khz.

Here are some questions:

- Does RemoteIO adopt the sample rate of whichever device it's outputting to? If I'm sending audio via HDMI to a device that asks for 48kz, do my RemoteIO callback buffers become 48khz?
- Is there some tidy way to just force RemoteIO to still think in terms of 44.1khz, and be smart enough to perform any necessary sample rate conversions on its own, before it hands data off to the device?
- If RemoteIO does indeed just defer to the device it's connected to, then presumably I need to do some sample rate conversion between my synthesis engine and remote IO. Is AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed my problem. I was incorrectly assuming that the number of frames requested by the render callback would be a power of two. Changed my code to accommodate any arbitrary number of frames and all seems to work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want sample rate conversion, try using the Audio Queue API, or do the conversion within your own app using some DSP code.

Whether the RemoteIO buffer size or sample rate can be configured or not might depend on iOS device model, OS version, audio routes, background modes, etc., so an app must accomodate different buffer sizes and sample rates when using RemoteIO.